# Calling a remote Java program on iSeries from RPG

Tags: java, ibm-midrange, rpg

I'm looking to invoke a Java program from RPG running on Iseries V5r4. The remote program is a web service client (performing a postcode lookup), running in Websphere.

Ideally I'd like to call it direct from RPG? is that possible? or do I have to create a java program to run on the iSeries and use RMI or something to call the remote java program.

We aren't keen on calling the extenral webservice direct as it means opening path from otherside world direct to iSeries.

I'm not an RPG programmer, just looking for something to point our guys in the right direction or anything I need to enable to make the java programs more consumable for the RPG folks.

Thanks, 
Scott

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Since the program is running on a remote server, you can't call it directly from RPG.  Given that it's a web service, I would create a Java program to run on the iSeries and call that Java program from within RPG.  Nowaday's, RPG can interface directly with Java.  You have to create some D-specs to declare the class and prototype out the method calls.  In the following example, assume a Java class exists called ServiceCaller in the package 'tools'.  It has a single method called getServiceReply which accepts three character fields and returns an integer.

```
 *Define the Java class locally.                                       
DServiceCaller    S               O   CLASS(*JAVA:'tools.ServiceCaller')

 *Class constructor.  No parameters.                                   
DnewServiceCaller PR              O   EXTPROC(*JAVA:                   
D                                       'tools.ServiceCaller':          
D                                       *CONSTRUCTOR)                  
D                                     CLASS(*JAVA:'tools.ServiceCaller')

 *GetServiceReply.
 *public int getServiceReply(byte[] parm1, byte[] parm2, byte[] parm3)
DgetServiceReply  PR            10I 0 EXTPROC(*JAVA:
D                                       'tools.ServiceCaller':
D                                       'getServiceReply')
D Parm1                        400A   CONST
D Parm2                        400A   CONST
D Parm3                        400A   CONST
```

Your RPG calc specs will look something like this free-form example:

```
/free
  ServiceCaller = newServiceCaller();
  iReply = getServiceReply(ServiceCaller:'Parm1':'Parm2':'Parm3');
/end-free
```

Inside the java code, within the getServiceReply method, convert those byte arrays to strings like this:

```
sParm1 = new String(parm1);
sParm2 = new String(parm2);
sParm3 = new String(parm3);
```

Granted, this is an oversimplified example and your application needs will be slightly different.  You will want to add error handling code in case the web service doesn't reply.  You may also want to use getters and setters in your class.  It all depends on your application needs and the requirements of the remote web service.

Some notes on RPG types to Java types:

```
RPG Type      Java Type
10I 0         int
 3I 0         byte
 5I 0         short
20I 0         long
  N           boolean
  A           byte[]
```

If you are feeling particularly ambitious, you can call the native Java HTTP classes from within your RPG.  But I've found that a custom Java program to act as an in-between that is written specifically to talk to RPG is an easier way to go.  Although RPG can talk to Java, it's not as pretty as Java talking to Java.

Additional information on calling Java from RPG can be found in the ILE RPG Programmer's guide.  The V5R4 version can be found here: http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/iseries/v5r4/topic/books/sc092507.pdf

Comment: great post thanks. 
How does RPG handle Java's Lists/Maps, I was told there isn't an equivlent (which can't believe). I need to return a array of potiental address matches?

Comment: You can pass arrays back and forth between Java and RPG, but not lists or maps.  I suggest using getter and setter methods.

Comment: When passing arrays, it's best to make an array of byte[] arrays in Java.  If you are using variable length character fields in RPG, it should be okay.  I never really embraced variable length character fields and, instead, I just have by Java create padded strings of the length needed in RPG and then convert them to byte arrays.

Comment: @Scotty: If it's great, upvote it; if it solved your problem, accept it too.

Answer (score 3):

Since the is a web service, another solution would be to use Scott Klement's HTTP API.  It's available on his website at http://www.scottklement.com/httpapi/.

One of the big benefits for me is this is entirely RPG and doesn't use any Java which can be a bit sluggish sometimes.  I'm not real familiar with how web services work in Java but it appears that you don't have to form all of the XML and it's done for you.  With the HTTP API you would need to do that yourself.

Also Scott Klement has several other useful things on his website.  Another site with some neat tools is http://www.think400.dk/downloads.htm.

Comment: I'd also recommend the httpapi.  I've used it in a production environment without trouble.

Comment: For any sufficiently complex WSDL this will be very tedious as the request and response XML's will be complex.